# Java 8 Optional.ofNullable.map producing Non static method reference error

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, in-memory-database

I have a method to verify a recipient of an email.

In my code `.map(Recipient::getId)` produces the error :

> Non static method cannot be reference from a static context.

```
private Long verifyRecipient(Long recipientId) throws NotFoundException {
    return Optional.ofNullable(recipientRepository.findById(recipientId))
            .map(Recipient::getId)
            .orElseThrow(()-> new NotFoundException("recipient with ID" + recipientId +
                    " was not found"));
}
```

`Recipient` class:

```
@Entity
public class Recipient {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @NotBlank
    @Email
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String emailAddress;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }
}
```

I am using SpringBoot and H2 in memory database.

So I also have a `RecipientRepository` interface:

```
public interface RecipientRepository extends JpaRepository<Recipient, Long> {}
```

Defination of the `findById()` method:

```
Optional<T> findById(ID var1);
```

Comment: If you use a similar logic with a instance build, this would be valid so I would guess `recipientRepository.findById(recipientId)` doesn't return a `Recipient` so the compiler expect to use a `static getId(SomeClass)` method where `SomeClass` is the type return by `findById`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `findById()` already returns an `Optional<T>`, so you don't need to wrap the result with additional `Optional.ofNullable()` in this situation.

Actually, the line:

```
Optional.ofNullable(recipientRepository.findById(recipientId));
```

returns `Optional<Optional<Recipient>>`, which is redundant.

Instead, you can just write:

```
private Long verifyRecipient(Long recipientId) throws NotFoundException {
    return recipientRepository.findById(recipientId)
        .map(Recipient::getId)
        .orElseThrow(() ->
            new NotFoundException("Recipient with ID " + recipientId + " was not found"));
}
```